# Copy 6th value of last line of text file, paste into another existing file

Tags: replace, sed, awk, text-processing

Let's say I have a file `copy_pars.txt`, and I want to extract the 6th, 7th, and 8th value on the last line, which looks something like this:

`detector xxx xxx xxx xxx XXX XXX XXX xxx xxx`

where the `XXX` values are the ones I want to copy. All values, besides the 1st one "`detector`", are unknown floats or integers, of unknown length. They are separated by single spaces.

I have a second file, `paste_pars.txt` in which I want to search for the **FIRST** line starting with "`detector`", and replace the 6th, 7th, and 8th values of the line with the ones from  `copy_pars.txt`.

I prefer to use `sed` or `awk`, but I'm welcome to suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this line:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{f6=$6;f7=$7;f8=$8;next}!f&&/^detector/{f=1;$6=f6;$7=f7;$8=f8}7' copy.txt paste.txt
```

didn't test, but should work for your requirement.

Comment: Thank you @Kent, worked great, except instead of changing `paste_pars.txt`, it output the whole thing directly to the terminal instead. I'm new to bash (and awk, obviously); how can I update `paste_pars.txt` without any output to the terminal?

Comment: Okay, I think I have answered my own question. I must rewrite to a new file, then rename this new file to overwrite the previous one: `awk 'blah blah' copy_pars.txt paste_pars.txt > paste_pars_new.txt && mv paste_pars_new.txt paste_pars.txt` If there is a better way that anyone knows of, please inform me!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{split($0,a);next} !f && /^detector/{for (i=6;i<=8;i++) $i=a[i]; f=1} 1' copy_pars.txt paste_pars.txt
```